# I want to do some api work in codeigniter,i am beginner with codeIgninter , I started studing codeigniter.know i want to know get the value from

Tags: codeigniter

I want to do some api work in codeigniter,I am beginner with codeIgniter , I started studying codeigniter. know i want to know how to send the value to view.

In View folder I have written like this:

```
<h1 align="center">Test Sample CI Framwork</h1>
<form name="f1" action="" method="post"/>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="" size="100" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" value=""  size="100"/>
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/></div>
</form>
<h1>The values from form:<?php echo $result; ?></h1>
```

IN controller:

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class add extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('add');
        $this->getvalue();
    }

    function getvalue()
 {
 if ($this->input->post('submit'))
 {

  $data=$this->input->post('firstname');
  $data=$this->input->post('lastname');
 //help me what i have to do here.
 }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can any guide me after this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, basically for transmit a data to the view, use :

```
$this->load->view('you-page',$data);
```

Your controller should be like this:

```
class add extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $data = array();

        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $data['firstname'] = $this->input->post('firstname');
            $data['lastname'] = $this->input->post('lastname');
        }

        $this->load->view('add', $data);
    }

}


////add.php////
<h1 align = "center">Test Sample CI Framwork</h1>
    <form name = "f1" action = "" method = "post"/>
        <input type = "text" name = "firstname" value = "" size = "100" />
        <input type = "text" name = "lastname" value = "" size = "100"/>
        <div>
             <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" name = "submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>

<h1>The values from form:<?=$firstname . '-' . $lastname?></h1>
```

Comment: Hi thank your so much for user answer.me and friend are working in this are you answering for both now we want to write crul you said to him we write crul.can you write the crul for this.http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com/busservices/auth/getAuthToken?namespaceCode=demo&username=ram%40demo.com&password=newnew&devicemedium=WEB you knew this errror failed to open stream:http request